# Magento Observers: with a deprecated implementation not yet removed?

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

```
//Mage.php   
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

I got confused by magento's observer implementation. There's a bunch of observer related classes in Varien library, but it seems Mage:app()->dispatchEvent doesn't use them as they are designed. There is one line commented out in Mage::dispatchEvent as shown above, am I right that Magento changed its Observer implementation from a load-per-area model to a load-per-event(with event cahce) model, and the commented out line is part of the deprecated implementation?

so it's safe to comment out the line as indicated in the following code in cron.php, and loadEventObservers is part of the deprecated implementation, right?

```
//Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
```